# css problems positioning div within div

Tags: css, html

im creating the footer for my site, i want social icons on the left, middle height, then footer links to some pages, then adress of the business, kind of like the layout on this sites footer, but i just cant get my head round how this code would be put together within a div?

the footer is 200px high, and 950 wide (centred) and this div has a footerbackground div behind 1920 wide and 200 high to give it a page wide background colour, then i have a footercontent which is 200 high 950 wide for all of the above to go in, the social icons i want 300 px wide by 70 px high? can anyone help me with this so hopefully i understand it better and can do it myself from now on?

CSS:

```
.footerbackground

{
background-color: #3c56a6;
height: 200px;
width: 1920px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top:10px 
}

.footercontent {
height: 200px;
width: 950px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;  


}

 .bigsocialicons {
height: 70px;
width: 292px;
margin-top: 62.5px;


 }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="footerbackground">

<div class="footercontent">

<div class="bigsocialicons">

<img src="images/facebookbig.png"/>
<img src="images/twitterbig.png"/>
<img src="images/googlebig.png"/>
<img src="images/linkedinbig.png"/>

</div>


</div>

</div>




 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Please create a JSFIDDLE so we can less imagine and can provide quick solution.

Comment: sorry guys i had a poor attempt but deleted it when i became frustrated! ill show you an example of something similar to the footer on this site http://www.securesiteuk.co.uk/ would be good, obviously with the icons as described above

Comment: added in the code i have so far, but the social icons are sticking to the top of the div even though i made them have a margin

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
.footerbackground
{
    background-color: #3c56a6;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1920px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top:10px 
}

.footerbackground .footercontent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.footerbackground .bigsocialicons {
    height: 70px;
    width: 292px;
    margin-top: 62.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
.bigsocialicons {
height: 70px;
width: 292px;
margin-top: 62.5px;
}
```

to

```
.bigsocialicons {
height: 70px;
width: 292px;
padding-top:62.5px;
}
```

If I understand correctly this is what you want to look it like. Just remember to adjust padding-top, since I don't know which height of images you are using.

Comment: this worked but how do i add in columns for the address and links?

Comment: if your footer have fixed height (as I can see now) you can just create 3 div blocks (like bigsocialicons) and give them "float: left", with desired padding. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5dqk5/ But remember to carefully adjust each div block width then.

Comment: but i dont know how to!